# Unity2D - messed up sprite while accesing it from script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, texture2d

I have 64x64 texture of tree :

[image]

but output gives me this (black messed object is my tree)

[image]

If i drag sprite into editor, its rendered as meant to be(with new gameobject created). But im accesing it through script :

```
public Sprite treesIcon;

SpriteRenderer sr;

TileTypeHandler typeHandler;

void Start () {
    sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}


void Update () {
    switch(typeHandler.tileType) /// nevermind enum, its edited
    {
        case TileType.Woods:
            {
                sr.sprite = treesIcon;
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

point is to dynamically change textures.

Can anyone explain me this behaviour? Is there somethin I am missing about sprites and textures? How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the editor (when running) of the `GameObject` you have the sprite set. I think this is a problem with the shader, or the alpha channel.

Comment: Actually you were right. It was problem with shader! Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result looks like the `SpriteRenderer` is using the wrong `shader`, change the Material to `Sprites-Default`, and it should work.

Would you have colored images, you immediately would see that there is something wrong, because they would also appear black.

Comment: this is case. I fell little embarrased because i did not noticed it.

Comment: @BobT. You don't have to. Why do you think I know the answer ... because I did the same!